# How Delete a Line With sed Without Leaving a Blank Line?

Tags: sed

File.txt:

```
line: this-is-some-text
line2: this-is-some-other-text
```

Example:

```bash
sed 's#line:.*##g' File.txt

line2: this-is-some-other-text
```

As you can see the first line has been deleted but is left with a blank line.

Can you execute `sed` so it doesn't leave a blank line on delete?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the **d**elete command rather than the **s**ubstitute command:

```
$ cat File.txt 
line: this-is-some-text
line2: this-is-some-other-text

$ sed '/line:/d' File.txt
line2: this-is-some-other-text
```

You might want to consider anchoring your expression to the start of the line, as `sed '/^line:/d' File.txt` .

Alternatively, consider a grep inverse match: `grep -v '^line:' File.txt` .

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '/line:/{next}1'
$ awk '/^line:/{next}1' #For pattern at the start of line
```

---

Using ed:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'v/line:/p'  | ed -s file
$ printf '%s\n' 'v/^line:/p'  | ed -s file # For pattern at the start of line
```